# Is it a bad practice to have a two line title in header?

Tags: material-design, header, title

I'm designing a banking application which is capable of money transfer and showing transactions of each account to the user.
Is it a bad practice to have a two line title in the header? The main title is Transactions(the current view) and the secondary title is the account number of the account the user is viewing.

[image]

Comment: It seems like it could fit on the right and have a bigger font-size (as right now it looks too small and without enough line-height), could this be an option?

Comment: Great idea, but again that raise another question, is it proper to have a two parted title? @Alvaro

Comment: You are right, and that is another good question.

Comment: "Bad practice" in terms of the Material Design guidelines or "bad practice" from a broader usability perspective?

Comment: I know in terms of Material Design the answer probably is "Yes, it is bad.", but I do want the answer from a broader usability perspective :). @MattObee

Comment: This is not a recommended design because the material design says don't wrap the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good question and I think it doesn't have a clear answer. If I understand correctly the context, the title of the page is "Transactions". The account number is actually the parent of this page.

Although you are not asking for Material design specifically I suggest you take a look to [Structure app bar](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar). In the bottom of the page there are some examples that make the Top bar double height so they can use the lower part as breadcrumb. I believe this might be a useful way of showing the hierarchy in your case.

[image]

The approach you have right now is clear, but using a double line in a short toolbar makes the line height too small and thus the text a bit cluttered.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually the parent is Transactions, and it gets even better when the parent is Transactions, because it makes the account number fully visible.

Comment: Or it isn't? I'm not sure whether it's better to choose the account number first and then do all the transactions and money transfers with that account or first choose the action he wants to take, then choose the account number he's going to do the actions like transferring money or viewing transactions with.

Comment: Shall I ask another question? :D

Comment: Is it possible for the user to give a name to his account rather than displaying a number?

Comment: @Jack-in-the-box it looks to me like it might be Ac.number > Transactions > TransactionX . But you know it better :p

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho in the Material link, there is a GIF/video with the footer "Right nav on mobile" and you can see it is also applied in a Mobile.

Comment: @Alvaro, you are right, that is why I edited my question :)

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho no problem :)

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho Yes it is, do you have another solution according to that? :D 
But in the patterns material suggests double height is not only for desktop view, but you're right it takes a lot of space...

Comment: @Alvaro so if it's accountnumber>transactions, the account number would not be fully visible in this design... :(

Comment: @Jack-in-the-box This will depend on the importance of displaying the account number in that screen. I suggest you keep the answer open in case others have better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered if revealing the full account number is really necessary at this point? If it's a banking application -- there are some sensitivities that you need to consider, especially displaying it boldly as a header. I believe the standard practice is that the number is hidden until requested to be shown. I would too consider using partial acct # or another proxy and in this way, you dont have to include the account # in the header at all.

Comment: In most countries we're not too fussed about exposing an account number as it doesn't pose any security treats.

Comment: The user may have different accounts and the only thing that makes them different is their account number, also what Martyn said is correct. There isn't any security problem with it. But what is your suggestion to show the difference between accounts not stating the account number? :) @Chris Jeong

Comment: Consider using an icon to distinguish the bank and show only the last 4 digits of the account